# Executing a sequence of time-consuming Android UI updates without hanging UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-maps

Disclaimer: it's possible I'm going about this in completely the wrong way & trying to solve the wrong problem.

I'm writing an Android app that uses Google Maps to show cloud cover over a 1km square area by adding a 1km-diameter circle to the map for each area with detected cloud cover via the following (probably naive) method:

```
CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions();
// ... set the center, radius, fillColor, strokeWidth, and strokeColor...
mMap.addCircle(options);
```

If there are just a few dozen circles added to the map, the performance is fine. If half the state of Florida is covered with clouds, the program chokes & hangs the UI for 5-30 seconds while it makes a few thousand calls to addCircle()

AsyncTask won't work here, because the time-consuming jobs are the calls to mMap.addCircle(), which HAVE to be made from the UI thread. I actually tried using doInBackground() to populate an array of CircleOptions, then iterated through it in onPostExecute() to make the calls to addCircle()... and as expected, it made absolutely no difference whatsoever to the app's performance (I think populating the CircleOptions array in doInBackground() shaved a whopping 18ms from the execution time on the UI thread).

In Unity, I could just use the Update() lifecycle method (which gets called once per video frame) and make 20-50 calls to addCircle() at a time before exiting to give it time to metaphorically go up for air and service the UI before the next batch. But AFAIK, Android Activity has no equivalent to this. You can do things that don't require UI changes in a background thread, then update the UI when it finishes... but there doesn't seem to be any explicit provision in Android for gracefully spreading multiple time-consuming UI updates across multiple frames.

So... DOES Android have some way to gracefully batch time-consuming UI updates across multiple frames a-la-Unity? Or is there a better way to render circle overlays onto a Google Map that can scale gracefully and handle thousands of such circles without choking?

Comment: IMHO, your problem isn't with Android; it is with the Maps API. "but there doesn't seem to be any explicit provision in Android for gracefully spreading multiple time-consuming UI updates across multiple frames" -- you can with `Choreographer` IIRC, though that's kinda low-level. You could use a `postDelayed()` "loop" to get control every 50ms or so and grab circles off of a queue to process. You could consider this to be an animation and try using the animator framework to get control every so often. Or you could wish for a better map API. :-)

Comment: I'll look into postDelayed, just because it's probably good enough for now. It's a shame postDelayed doesn't allow negative values for delay time with various overloaded meanings, like -1 = "fully service the UI, then execute", -2 = "wait until the next video frame", -3 = both, etc.